# TopBar in foundation 6 not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

My topbar in foundation 6 is somehow not working (Not somehow, the foundation.topbar.js isn't there). So, please help me get it added.

I'm new to foundation — like a total noob. I'm 13. So, please consider that. :)

And here's the **WHOLE** code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="top-bar">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1><i>Title</i></h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="callout">
          <h1>HEADER</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/foundation-5.2.2/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is what happens:

[image: This is what happens...]

This is my JS folder:

[image: this is my js folder]

Answer (score 2):

just you're coding in Foundation 5.x style. Look at this : http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

thank you. and also download and import the .js folder from the foundation on git.
the the topbar will "work".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just running this as a static page (html)

Yet in the path for your javascript includes you're including

```
<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```

Which looks to be a php function

Might I suggest you run the likes of WAMPserver ( given you're running windows it's a simple way of getting Apache Mysql and PHP up and running on your local machine.

Additional note: As was said however it looks like you're including foundation 5.x code

```
"<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/foundation-5.2.2/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"
```